# Add-On Domain Redirects to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https, addon-domain

I have a GoDaddy shared hosting account with one main domain that uses SSL and now an add-on domain that I do not want to use SSL. I would like to redirect non-https to https for the main domain BUT NOT for the add-on domain. Both sites use Wordpress.

*To be clear, the **main domain should use https**, the **add-on domain should not use https.***

The problem I am experiencing is addondomain.com is redirecting to **https**://addondomain.com.

I know the problem can be fixed through my .htaccess file, and I have made several attempts, but each one ends with the add-on domain redirecting back to the main domain. Any insight as to what I need to change on my .htaccess file would be very much appreciated!

Here is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect just the maindomain to  https, just add the following  condition to your rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
##if host=="*maindomain.com"##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$
##and scheme ==http(https off)##
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
##then redirect the site to https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```